# Estimating a max poolsize in azure postgres

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling

[In this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/estimating-connection-pool-size-with-postgresql-database-statistics/) , I found the formula to get an estimate of the max poolsize value:

```
connections < max(num_cores, parallel_io_limit) /
              (session_busy_ratio * avg_parallelism)
```

now, there's a way to calculate the `session_busy_ratio` given as a query in the article, what I'm stuck at are two parameters: `parallel_io_limit` and `avg_parallelism`. Now, azure does provide a `max_iops` value for it's plans, e.g. For a `8core 32gb mem` a value of `12800 max iops` is given, but, I'm not sure if this is the value to be used here. And I actually don't know how to find out the `avg_parallelism` for which the article says:

> avg_parallelism is the average number of backend processes working on a single query.

I'd really like some help to understand what these parameters really are and how to find them, also some more explanation of the `system_busy_ratio` could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The “average parallelism” is not a parameter, but something that depends on your queries and your setting of `max_parallel_workers` and `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`. If `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` is 0, the average parallelism must be 1.

If it is a hosted database, you don't know the number of parallel I/O requests that your storage can handle.

Comment: how would you suggest estimate pool size with such a formula for hosted databases? I mean some empirical drills could be helpful to estimate based on throughput metrics, but, some theoritical grounds could be assuring as well

Comment: The only people who have that information are at your hosting provider. That's one of the key points about hosting a service: you entrust the integrity of your data and the performance of your application to somebody else. If they don't help you, perhaps you should rethink that decision.